# How do you preserve the window.performance.getEntries() values across multiple pages in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onbeforeunload

I have a requirement for preserving all the AJAX call entries in `window.performance.getEntries()`, especially those dumped between page transitions. This is being used for monitoring of errors and statistics. It is stored in an external service.

I'm proposing to do something like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    storageServiceCall(window.performance.getEntries());
}
```

I think there is probably standard way to do this in AngularJS involving the routing of page transitions, or exiting the Angular SPA.

The concern of the statistics requirement is that some values in ‘window.page.getEntries()’ are lost forever on a page transition. The requirement wants to preserve all of them.

My question is: **How do you preserve the window.performance.getEntries() values across multiple pages in AngularJS?**

Comment: In real SPA, onbeforeunload is never triggered... And if you actually change page, I doupt you can keep any js objects

Comment: What do you mean by reserve? You want to store that data each time a change in url occurs?

Comment: Thanks @PetrAveryanov - agree with your point. It is worth adding that this SPA has some bolt-ons.